# Kendo UI saveAsPDF failes, but saveAsExcel works?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI in a project. On one page, it has a chart and grid. I added 2 export button (not the button from kendo), one for PDF and one for excel. when they are clicked, the code is at below:

```
$("#btnGridExcelExport").click(function () {
    $("#grid").getKendoGrid().saveAsExcel();
});

$("#btnGridPdfExport").click(function () {
    $("#grid").getKendoGrid().saveAsPDF();
});
```

However, for some reasons, saveAsExcel works fine, but saveAsPDF fails. it does not export anything, and the browser seems got frozen although it did not. I can see the progress bar, but seems never finished the 'progress'.

[image]

Obviuosly, $("#grid").getKendoGrid() is not NULL, that's why exporting excel works fine. But then why saveAsPDF() did  not work?

I also use below code to save chart as pdf, it works:

```
$("#btnChartPdfExport").click(function () {
    var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();
    chart.exportPDF({ paperSize: "auto", margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" } }).done(function (data) {
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: '@ViewData["ReportName"]'+" chart.pdf"
        });
    });
});
```

I also used the export button coming with grid, same issue: excel works, but pdf does not:

```
toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
```

Why $("#grid").getKendoGrid().saveAsPDF() not work? Anyone had this issue? What can cause this? Could it because of Acrobat version or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Any console errors? If it is too big you may  need a proxyUrl parameter.

Comment: no console error. just looks like the progress bar stopped, and seems frozen. But actually not. and the size is not large, just 2-3 pages.

Comment: Does [this exmaple](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/saveaspdf) work for you?

Comment: Facing the same problem when using saveAsPDF() on button click event the screen gets freezed with a progress bar on it. How do I export my kendo grid data to pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and adding this fixed it for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>        
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

My code:
$("#exportToPdf").click(function(e) {
        var grid = $("#CommentsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.saveAsPDF();
    });